# Getting message using pyrogram

Tags: python, bots, telegram, pyrogram

I've tried to write a telegram bot using pyrogram. Can you help me figure out how to write a bot correctly.
It include menu, button "Transfer balance", next telegram must ask username, and later amount of balance. At the end it must show us what we texted (username : username, balance : amount), and button "Confirm".
I have searched to much on the net, but I couldn't find necessary information. Hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

I've tried to search information on the Net, using chat bot, asking friend. But nothing were able to help me.

Comment: Could you try to frame your requirements a bit more clearly, also using proper formatting, e.g. a bullet list.